# org.json.JSONException: No value for all_advertisement

Tags: android, json

I have created a application. In this application there is a advertisement module. This module is divided into two portions:

1. create an advertisement
2. view advertisement

But when I click on the vies advertisement the following error occurs in the Log-cat.
The following code display that there is no value for all_advertisement.but the value i enter for the parameter is successfully stored in the database.

```
    07-07 04:32:12.643: W/System.err(3306):    org.json.JSONException: No value for all_advertisements
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.ViewAdvertise$ViewAdvertisement.doInBackground(ViewAdvertise.java:99)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.ViewAdvertise$ViewAdvertisement.doInBackground(ViewAdvertise.java:1)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    07-07 04:32:12.653: W/System.err(3306):     at
```

Module one is working properly. After creating the advertisement and filling up the parameters (like name, mobile, state) and adding description of add, clicking on the send button creates the advertisement and stores the value in the database. The value are stored in JSON format.

code id

```
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data1);

            Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));
            if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
            {


            JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_advertisement");  
            Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));




            for (int j=0; j < jArray.length(); j++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    mname = jsob.getString("name");   
                    mobile = jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr");   
                    state = jsob.getString("states");   
                    desc = jsob.getString("desc");   


                    nameArray.add(jsob.getString("name").toString());

                    mobileArray.add(jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr").toString());

                    stateArray.add(jsob.getString("states").toString());

                    descArray.add(jsob.getString("desc").toString());

                    HashMap<String, String> adHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    adHash.put("name", jsob.getString("name").toString());

                    adHash.put("mbl_nmbr", jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr").toString());

                    adHash.put("states", jsob.getString("states").toString());

                    adHash.put("desc", jsob.getString("desc").toString());

                    //adsArray.add(adHash);

                      // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewAdvertise.this, R.layout.listrow, stateArray);
```

}

```
response.


07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434): {
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):     "data": [
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):         {
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "id": "53",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "desc": "",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "status": "2",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "name": "vivek",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "states": "",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "mbl_nmbr": "",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "user_id": "45",
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):             "date_time": "2014-07-07 05:16:29"
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):         }
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):     ],
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434):     "err-code": "0"
07-08 01:19:39.547: D/response(1434): }
```

COMPLETE JAVA CODE

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_ads);
        pref=this.getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        login_token = pref.getString("login_token","login_token"); 
        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);   
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        tv4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text6);
        new ViewAdvertisement().execute();

    }
    private class ViewAdvertisement extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
        String mname,mobile,state,desc;

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                JSONObject job1= new JSONObject();
                try 
                {
                    job1.put("status_key","2");
                    job1.put("method", "view_add");
                    job1.put("state", state);
                    job1.put("login_token", login_token);

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job1.toString());

                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/DGCapp/webservice.php");



                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String data1 = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
                    System.out.println("response "+data1);



                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data1);

                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));
                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                    {


                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_advertisement");  
                    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));




                    for (int j=0; j < jArray.length(); j++)
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(j);

                            mname = jsob.getString("name");   
                            mobile = jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr");   
                            state = jsob.getString("states");   
                            desc = jsob.getString("desc");   


                            nameArray.add(jsob.getString("name").toString());

                            mobileArray.add(jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr").toString());

                            stateArray.add(jsob.getString("states").toString());

                            descArray.add(jsob.getString("desc").toString());

                            HashMap<String, String> adHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            adHash.put("name", jsob.getString("name").toString());

                            adHash.put("mbl_nmbr", jsob.getString("mbl_nmbr").toString());

                            adHash.put("states", jsob.getString("states").toString());

                            adHash.put("desc", jsob.getString("desc").toString());

                            //adsArray.add(adHash);

                              // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewAdvertise.this, R.layout.listrow, stateArray);   

                        } 
                        catch (JSONException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                    }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewAdvertise.this);
                alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                alert.setMessage("No Internet connection ");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        //pDialog.dismiss();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return params;

        }             

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
        {


            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //  adapter.clear();
            /*adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  */
            //  adapter.clear();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewAdvertise.this, R.layout.listrow, stateArray);   

            list.setAdapter(adapter);   

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            //  adapter.addAll(stateArray);



            /*tv1.setText(desc);
            tv2.setText(mname);
            tv3.setText(mobile);
            tv4.setText(state);*/

            System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
            Iterator<String> itr = nameArray.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String element = itr.next();
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();   


            System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
            Iterator<String> itr1 = stateArray.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String element = itr1.next();
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();   
            //  ListView lv = getListView();

            // listening to single list item on click
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                int position;

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // selected item 
                    // String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    long index = parent.getSelectedItemId();
                    this.position=position;
                    // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewAds.class);
                    // sending data to new activity

                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("nameArray", nameArray);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("mobileArray", mobileArray);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("stateArray", stateArray);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("descArray", descArray);

                    //i.putExtra("adArray", adsArray);

                    i.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

on server side

function view_add($data)
{
    $user_id = NULL;

```
if ($user_id = getUser($data -> login_token))
{
    $status_key     = mysql_real_escape_string($data->status_key);
    $msg = array();

    $get_state = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT State FROM advertisement where id='$user_id'"));
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE states='{$get_state['State']}'");

    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        while($add = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $msg[] = $add;
        }
        return array("err-code" => '0', "data" => $msg);
    }
    else
    {
        return array("message" => "There is no Add for you.", "err-code" => "400");
    }
}
else
{
    return array("err-code"=>"1","data"=>"Session Expired");
}
```

}

Comment: you have an error on `JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_advertisement"); ` see Tags on `jo` to find correct Tag, you don't have any Tag as `all_advertisement` as your log says `org.json.JSONException: No value for all_advertisements`

Comment: but the value store in the database.please check the response i have edit above...

Comment: @user3736827 post the json response here

Comment: @Raghunandan  I have post the response as you say check that

Comment: @user3736827 where is JSONArray `all_advertisement`? I  don't see that in the response

Comment: So? Your response does not have a key "all_advertisement". Check your server side.

Comment: your response doesn't contain "all_advertisement" JSONArray so check your server side response again or change this line JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_advertisement");  into JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: change `all_advertisements` to `data`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `jo.getJSONArray("all_advertisement");` android will look for a jsonArray with the key `all_advertisement` in the `jo` Object. However, the sample JSON String that you posted doesnt contain any array with that key. Your parsing mechanism should look something like this :

```
String response = //contains your JSON String. 
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
//Since you have only one object in the data array, 
//you can use get(0) but incase you have multiple objects 
//just loop through the array to retrieve all 
//required objects from the data array.
String id = jArray.get(0).getString("id");
String desc = jArray.get(0).getString("desc");
...
...
```